# Array filling up with Pending Promises?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am so close to finishing the base of this function but i am stuck, and its a little todo with my lack of knowledge in promises and i am learning how they function etc. Regarding my issue, i am looping through some data that is then being stored in an Array that will be passed to another function via promise chain, however the array is being filled with pending promises where i just need the actual data from the promise placed into the array, please see below to understand whats going on:

```
var getGameData = function(matchIdArray) {
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
  console.log('Start getGameData');
  s3.headObject({Bucket: 'lolsearchgames', Key: '347341'}, function(err, result) {
    console.log('Checking Bucket');
    if (err && err.code === 'NotFound') {
      console.log('Bucket data Not Found!')
      var gameData = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < matchIdArray.length; i++) {
        gameData.push(new Promise(function(res, rej) {
          lolapi.Match.get(matchIdArray[i], function (error, gamedata) {
            if (error) {
                rej(error);
            }
            if (gamedata) {
                console.log('Pushing new data to Array! ' + gamedata.matchId);
                res(gamedata);
            }
          })
        }));
      }
      if (gameData.length === 10) {
          console.log(gameData);
          resolve(gameData);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Bucket data Found!');
    }
  })
});
return promise;
console.log('End getGameData');
};
```

Comment: `Promise.all` on an array of promises returns a promise that resolves to an array of results when they ALL resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Promise.all to wait for all the "gameData" as follows - also use Array#map to avoid having to push to an array

Note: however, that if there's any rejection in any lolapi.Match.get promise, the Promise.all will reject - this may not be what you want, I'm not sure from your code example

```
var getGameData = function getGameData(matchIdArray) {
  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Start getGameData');
    s3.headObject({ Bucket: 'lolsearchgames', Key: '347341' }, function (err, result) {
      console.log('Checking Bucket');
      if (err && err.code === 'NotFound') {
        console.log('Bucket data Not Found!');
        Promise.all(matchIdArray.map(function(matchId) {
          return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
            lolapi.Match.get(matchId, function (error, gamedata) {
              if (error) {
                rej(error);
              }
              res(gamedata);
            });
          })
        }))
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
      } else {
        console.log('Bucket data Found!');
        reject('Bucket data Found!');
      }
    });
  });
  console.log('End getGameData');
  return promise.then(function (results) {  // see note below
    return results.filter(function (result) {
      return result;
    });
  });
};
```

Alternative - and I think "tidier" code

```
var getGameData = function getGameData(matchIdArray) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log('Start getGameData');
        s3.headObject({
            Bucket: 'lolsearchgames',
            Key: '347341'
        }, function(err, result) {
            console.log('Checking Bucket');
            if (err && err.code === 'NotFound') {
                console.log('Bucket data Not Found!');
                resolve();
            } else {
                console.log('Bucket data Found!');
                reject('Bucket data Found!');
            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return Promise.all(matchIdArray.map(function(matchId) {
            return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
                lolapi.Match.get(matchId, function(error, gamedata) {
                    if (error) {
                        rej(error);
                    }
                    res(gamedata);
                });
            })
        }));
    }).then(function (results) {  // see note below
        return results.filter(function (result) {
            return result;
        });
    });
}
```

If you use Bluebird promises, it has utility methods to "promisify" node callback style functions - in the code below, `s3.headObjectAsync` is the promisified version of `s3.headObject` and `lolapi.Match.getAsync` is the promisified version of `lolapi.Match.get`

You'll see, using bluebirds promisify, (and ES2015+ arrow notation, since you are using node) makes your code far more compact

```
var getGameData = function getGameData(matchIdArray) {
    return s3.headObjectAsync({
        Bucket: 'lolsearchgames',
        Key: '347341'
    })
    // do some gymnastics, because if there's no error, that should reject
    // but if the error is "NotFound" that should resolve
    .then(results => {
        throw {code: 'Bucket data Found!'};
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (err && err.code === "NotFound") {
            return; // this is OK
        }
        throw err;
    })
    .then(() => Promise.all(matchIdArray.map(matchId => lolapi.Match.getAsync(matchId))))
    .then(results => results.filter(result => result)); // see note below
}
```

In ES5 code the above is still pretty compact

```
var getGameData = function getGameData(matchIdArray) {
    return s3.headObjectAsync({
        Bucket: 'lolsearchgames',
        Key: '347341'
    }).then(function (results) {
        throw { code: 'Bucket data Found!' };
    }).catch(function (err) {
        if (err && err.code === "NotFound") {
            return; // this is OK
        }
        throw err;
    }).then(function () {
        return Promise.all(matchIdArray.map(function (matchId) {
            return lolapi.Match.getAsync(matchId);
        }));
    }).then(function (results) {  // see note below
        return results.filter(function (result) {
            return result;
        });
    });
};
```

> Please note in all these answers, the result would not be exactly what you would expect given your original code. In your original code, if `gamedata` was falsey you just ignored that "Match.get" ... however, you can't do that with Promises - the last .then in the answers filters out the empty results in the promise returned by `getGameData`

Comment: Avoid the promise constructor antipattern!

Comment: @Bergi - yes, I was going to add that, but the logic in `s3.headObject` confused me because it rejects if NOT err!!

Comment: @Bergi - I've added a version that relies on bluebirds promisify - I can't see any other easy way of avoiding the promise constructor antipattern when using functions that have node style callbacks - to be honest, I'm not sure your comment is justified in this case, because, lets face it, bluebirds promisify (or promise/then's denodeify) does the Promise constructor for you - so you're not avoiding it, you're chainging where it is done

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with using the promise constructor for promisification of `headObject` and `get`, the *antipattern* only refers to using other promises (notably `Promise.all` and its constituents) inside a promise constructor callback. Your second snippet is totally fine.

Comment: @Bergi - the second snippet has exactly the same number of Promise constructors (two) as the first, so I guess the phrase `Avoid the promise constructor antipattern` doesn't mean what I thought it means, i.e. avoid using `new Promise` where it's not required

Comment: I guess I refer to everything that "does too much inside a `new Promise` callback" as the promise constructor antipattern, especially when it uses another promise inside: `new Promise((res, rej) => { … promise.then(res, rej) … });` Sometimes the `…` is a piece of sync code, sometimes async code that requires the actual promisification.

Comment: All good @Bergi - that's why I added the second bit of code to begin with, I didn't like the `Promise.all(...).then(resolve).catch(reject);` code at all

Comment: @JaromandaX is it possible to add another .then() where i will use s3.putObject function but still be able to pass the games onwards ?

Comment: I have no idea how the `s3.putObject` relates to your code

Comment: Basically and .then functiom before .then resolve that will pass the data to s3 online before i resolve?

Comment: I can rewrite it if you would like so you understand